How to capture a Patient's healthcare literacy in FHIR?
Objective
For a specific use case we need to capture a Patient's healthcare proficiency. For that we have three classifications, eg literate, informed, and curious.
Question
What is the FHIR conformant way (resource, extension, etc) to store this?
Context

We capture the patient's healthcare proficiency via Questionnaire and QuestionnaireResponse.
With a Subscription to QuestionnaireResponse we trigger the post processing in the backend.
Our backed is tasked to turn the QuestionnaireResponse into a FHIR conformant structure.
We make use of StructureMap to define the mapping from QuestionnaireResponse to target FHIR resources.

Hence which target resource or other FHIR conformant way to store this data?

There is not a specific element in the Patient resource to store 'literacy in healthcare'.
I assume you want to keep this information inside the Patient resource rather than a related resource.
I would propose at least two different conformant ways:

Use a string extension
Use a metadata tag

Here are the examples:
string extension
{
  "resourceType": "Patient",
  "id": "123456",
  "extension": [
    {
      "url": "http://example.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/literacy",
      "valueString": "informed"
    }
  ],
  "name": [
    {
      "use": "official",
      "family": "Doe",
      "given": [
        "John"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "gender": "male",
  "birthDate": "1980-01-01"
}

metadata tag
{
  "resourceType": "Patient",
  "id": "123456",
  "meta": {
    "tag": [
      {
        "system": "http://example.org/fhir/CodeSystem/literacy",
        "code": "informed"
      }
    ]
  },
  "name": [
    {
      "use": "official",
      "family": "Doe",
      "given": [
        "John"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "gender": "male",
  "birthDate": "1980-01-01"
}


Consider the tag approach may be easier to filter by most FHIR applications.

thanks, Jaime. As per your comment, the metatag solution makes more sense
